# Change menu when front user loggs in - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I have two menus, difference is only one page. I have front end users build using 'front end only user' plugin. I want to show one menu when user is logged out and secon when user is logged in. 
I have tried severaln plugins 'nav  role menu' i 'if menu' but they are not working.

Also tried with this code but 0 success.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
} else { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

What might be a problem.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7999/change-front-end-menu-depending-on-user-login

Comment: this is not working too. I have no idea what is problem. 0 success with everything

Answer (score 0):

use this snippet or override your current code to display the menus in theme.

```
<?php
if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'login-menu');
} else { 
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logout-menu');
} 
?>
```

hope this will helps you.

For more information.

- [Show Different Navigation Menu to your Members and Non-members](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wordpress-membership/show-different-navigation-menu-to-your-members-and-non-members-551)
- [Showing a different menu in Primary Navigation location conditionally in Genesis](https://gist.github.com/srikat/5d40d43cd2df122fed41)